# How can I quickly get titles of videos in YouTube playlist using pytube?

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I need to get 1, a list of video links of a playlist and 2, list of video names of a playlist. This is what I am doing.

```
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist

playlist_link = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJKfZ_cKGyLdYqdzGLCJPbsi9UGCcEc5e"

video_links = Playlist(playlist_link).video_urls

video_titles = []
for link in video_links:
    video_titles.append(YouTube(link).title)
```

While this works, getting all the titles takes forever because each link has to be converted to a YouTube object, is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at your code and it takes around 22 seconds to execute.

```
from time import time
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist

playlist_link = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJKfZ_cKGyLdYqdzGLCJPbsi9UGCcEc5e"

video_links = Playlist(playlist_link).video_urls

video_titles = []
start = time()
for link in video_links:
    video_titles.append(YouTube(link).title)

print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
# output
Time taken: 21.815414667129517
```

You can reduce the execution time by adding multithreading.  The following code takes about 3 seconds to execute.

```
from time import time
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

playlist_link = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJKfZ_cKGyLdYqdzGLCJPbsi9UGCcEc5e"
video_links = Playlist(playlist_link).video_urls
start = time()


def get_video_title(link):
    title = YouTube(link).title
    return title


processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for url in video_links:
        processes.append(executor.submit(get_video_title, url))

video_titles = []
for task in as_completed(processes):
    video_titles.append(task.result())
    print(task.result())


print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
# output
Time taken: 2.7463150024414062
```